# A population growth model that exceeds carrying capacity and then falls rapidly

Tags: population-dynamics

I have tried exploring different periodic functions combined with exponential growth rates, however, all my models fail to overshoot the carrying capacity. I have also examined piece-wise functions that could work, however something that is more elegant would be much more pleasing.

Comment: Are you looking for an ODE ? What are your trials ? You need to provide more details.

Comment: Yes an ODE, my trials are:
dN/dt=rN (1-N/(a sin⁡b(t+c)+d))
dN/dt = rN(1-N/K) - cK

Comment: Because of the Lipschitz theorem, I think you have to consider second order equations at least. Because the carrying capacity should be an equilibrium state, doesn't it ?

Comment: That's exactly my intention: exploring varrying carrying capacities with boom and bust cycles